# Translation push job from external activity failing

Tags: web8.5, workflow, translation-manager, api

I am trying to trigger a translation job from an external workflow activity on a Web 8.5 instance. When I save the TranslationJobData I get the following error:

> ERROR Project.Workflow.SendTranslationActivityWorker - System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.Data.TmServiceFault]: Nullable object must have a value. (Fault Detail is equal to Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.Data.TmServiceFault)

I am pushing the job using the following code:

```
public static string Translate(string userId, string title, string publicationId, IEnumerable<string> items, bool includeItemsAlreadyTranslated)
{
    using (SessionAwareTmServiceClient tmClient = new SessionAwareTmServiceClient("TmBinaryEndpointV2"))
    {

        TranslationJobData job = tmClient.CreateJob(title, publicationId, Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.Data.TranslationJobType.PushJob);

        job.RequiredDate = DateTime.Now;
         job.Priority = Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.Data.TranslationJobPriority.High;

        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            job.AddedItems.Add(new AddedItemData() { TcmUri = item });
        }
        job.IncludeItemsAlreadyTranslated = includeItemsAlreadyTranslated;
        job.State = Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.Data.TranslationJobState.ReadyForTranslation;

        tmClient.SaveJob(job);

        return job.Id.ToString();
     }
 }
```

`Project.Workflow.SendTranslationActivityWorker` calls `Translate` directly, and thus throws the error.

I've confirmed that the error does occur on the `tmClient.SaveJob(job);`
I've also confirmed that none of the values I am adding to the job are null and that none of the values I am using to create the job are null.
I've confirmed that I am using the correct endpoint on my tmClient.
I can manually translate items with the same configuration as the items I am trying to translate through workflow, in the same publication.

Comment: You should look in log of TM on server when it is happening. Stacktrace will show where it fails.

Comment: But now when I thinking about this. You also need to specify ResolveInfo when you create AddedItem. Like this  new AddedItemData() { TcmUri = item; ResolveInfo = ResolveInfo.TranslateParentItems | ResolveInfo.TranslateSubItems }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to specify ResolveInfo when you create AddedItem.

```
job.AddedItems.Add(new AddedItemData() {
                                          TcmUri = item,
                                          ResolveInfo = ResolveInfo.TranslateParentItems | ResolveInfo.TranslateSubItems
                                       });
```